# accessing changed value of exported variable

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a module "a" which exports a variable initiated as `null`. This variable is imported into module "b".

Following some changes to the initial variable, I try to access it again from module "b", only to find I get the original `null` value.

Aren't these variables being imported as reference? Meaning, they should reflect any changes made to them at a later point in runtime.

```js
// main.js
import * as a from './a.js'
import * as b from './b.js'

// a.js
let test = null
export default test

export function change() {
  test = 'test'
  console.log(['in a.js change()', test])
}
console.log(['in a.js global', test])

// b.js
import test, { change } from './a.js'

console.log(['in b.js, pre a.change()', test])
change()
console.log(['in b.js, post a.change()', test])


/*
output:
Array [ "in a.js global", null ]
Array [ "in b.js, pre a.change()", null ]
Array [ "in a.js change()", "test" ]
Array [ "in b.js, post a.change()", null ]   WHY ISN'T THIS = "test" ?
*/
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Aren't these variables being imported as reference? Meaning, they should reflect any changes made to them at a later point in runtime.

No.  When you imported the variable, you made a copy of it into a new variable.  That copy will not change if the original variable gets something new assigned to it.

When you do this:

```
import test, { change } from './a.js'
```

You're assigning the exported default value into a new variable named `test`.  That new variable has no connection with the other variable any more.

There are several ways to provide access to the changed variable:

1. **Export an object where the variable is a property on that object.**  Then, in your original module, change the value of that property.  In this case, the imported  module will have a pointer to the same object so when you access the property on that object, you will see the new value.
2. **Export a method** that retrieves the current value of the variable from within the module.
3. **Create an event** which an outside module can listen for and fire that event anytime the value of the variable changes.

Remember that plain values are assigned by making a copy of the value and inserting it into the new variable.  Objects, on the other hand, are assigned by making a copy of the pointer to the same object and putting that pointer into the new variable.  So, with objects the new variable contains a pointer to the same object.

Answer (score 4):

The functionality you're expecting can't be observed with a *default* export, as already explained, but it will occur with a *named* export (unfortunately):

```
// a.js
export let test = null;

export function change() {
  test = "test";
  console.log(["in a.js change()", test]);
}
console.log(["in a.js global", test]);
```

and

```
// b.js

import { test, change } from "./a.js";

console.log(["in b.js, pre a.change()", test]);
change();
console.log(["in b.js, post a.change()", test]);
```

Here, the imported `test` *changes*, because it's a named import.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-liskov-se4fh

This sort of behavior is very unintuitive, because to the consuming module, it kind of looks like what *seemed* to be a primitive magically reassigns itself, which looks crazy from any other context of Javascript. This is why it's often recommended never to reassign exported variables. Use a different method, like the ones in jfriend00's answer.