# Using a form input as a const to import into an API endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to React and I am having trouble in my Next.js app with imports and exports. I want to export a const from a form component to an API endpoint in order to use it in a function.

I am getting the form component variable to populate in `console.log(formData)`, but it is not passing through to my endpoint as I would expect.

Here is my code for the `FormComponent`. I would like to export the data from the form to be used in the API endpoint.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export let formData = {
  name: '',
  email: '',
  message: '',
};

const FormComponent = () => {
  const [localFormData, setLocalFormData] = useState(formData);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setLocalFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    formData = localFormData;
    console.log(formData);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={localFormData.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Email:
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={localFormData.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Message:
        <textarea
          name="message"
          value={localFormData.message}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default FormComponent;
```

And then to import that state to my API endpoint I use the following, but `formData` remains undefined.

```
import { formData } from './FormComponent';
export default async function handler(req) {
try{
const results= ${formData.email}
}
}
```

Comment: Might be helpful [accessing changed value of exported variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720857/accessing-changed-value-of-exported-variable)

Comment: It’s not an import/export problem. Check the below answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handler` is an [API Route](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes) that runs on the server while the `formData` you are exporting and manipulating is on the client. You cannot exchange data between the two with `export`/`import`.

You need to send the data to the API as part of a POST request, like below for example:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const FormComponent = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    message: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await fetch("/api/endpoint", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" value={formData.name} onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" name="email" value={formData.email} onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Message:
        <textarea name="message" value={formData.message} onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default FormComponent;
```

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); //  The data you have sent is here.
  res.json({ message: "Ok" });
}
```