# If I change a value of a variable, will it update in a file that exported it?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I we have the file `main.js` with the  following code:

```
var count = 0
function increase(){
    count = count + 1
}
export default count
```

In which the function `increase()` is called when a button is clicked.

Now if we import the variable count from a different file, let's say `index.js`. After that we press the button. Will the value in `index.js` update? and if no then how to do so?

Comment: why not try first then you will see the answer

Comment: Also it sounds like you're trying to do something, but you came up with a solution and that solution doesn't work, so you're asking about how to fix that solution, instead of asking how to tackle the original problem. I.e. this is [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Your exports should be stable. If you need a counter, export a function that yields that counter's value, don't export the counter variable.

Comment: how can I track the change of a value from a different file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing changed value of exported variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720857/accessing-changed-value-of-exported-variable)

Comment: tldr: use export instead of export default

Comment: @Konrad - `export count` will not solve the problem either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now if we import the variable count from a different file, let's say index.js. After that we press the button. Will the value in index.js update? and if no then how to do so?

No, it will not update.  When you import a primitive value like a number, you're getting the value at the time you import it and that value is then assigned as a copy to your new variable (whatever variable you imported it into).  It will no longer have anything to do with the imported variable in the original file.

The usual way to import/export something that will update is by exporting an object with properties.  Objects (unlike primitives) are assigned and imported by copying a reference to the same object.

```
const obj = { count: 0 };
function increase(){
    obj.count++;
}
export obj;
```

Then, you can import that object from another file and the `count` property in that object will reflect any changes made in either file because you will both have pointers to the exact same object and thus be accessing the same property in that object.